# React formik on Blur Field value not working Fine

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have an input for User Name. On the on Blur event of that input I check on DB if the User Name exists. If the user Name  exists, I want to show error. But not working fine.
Please Help us

code Sandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselect-formik-3eqxp?file=/src/RegisterForm.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your onBlur with this.

```
onBlur={() => validCheck(values.name)}
```

Now in your validCheck you can make the API call

```
 const validCheck = (name) => {
   if(name.trim().length === 0){
     return;
   } 
   // make the API call here
   console.log(name);
  };
```